# htaccess file not redirecting root level request to sub-directory level

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web-hosting

I was having my wordpress website which domain `example.com` installed on root directory which is `public_html` recently I migrate my website content to a sub-directory `public_html/my_subdir`. to load the content from the sub-directory I modified the `.htaccess` file which is placed on `public_html` root folder to load the content from the sub-directory where I placed the website content.

Now my `.htaccess` file working fine when I hit the URL `example.com` it loads the content from my sub-directory which is `public_html/my_subdir` but when I go to `example.com/wp-admin` or `example.com/contactus` or any other path except root domain then it will load content from the root directory itself not from the sub-directory `public_html/my_subdir`.

below is the `.htaccess` file which I placed on root level,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Did I miss anything here, please help me to point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [per instruction](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), all content is supposed to be moved to a subdirectory, leaving only `.htaccess` in the root.
Since you wrote `it will load content from the root directory`, I guess there are some files left in the root.
These two conditions are canceling rewrite if the requested file or directory are presented:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Therefore, I suggest removing content from the root.

Otherwise, I guess it is possible to create simple `.htaccess` in the root that will be just redirecting to a subdirectory while adding a standard WordPress `.htaccess` in the subdirectory itself.

Basically, a final solution depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to use my subdirectory here, I can also remove the content, but i don't want take risk by removing something important from tehre. If I delete the wordpress site which is install on root will it only remove wordpress related content or other files and folder also